# creating array in javascript from array object pass in by request.setAttribute in servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

i'm trying to create a dynamic photo gallery which retrieve the photo's location from mySQL. Store the location to a photo object under the name '`private String location;`'
There will be an ArrayList to hold all the different photos. After, the servlet will forward to a jsp page

```
request.setAttribute("list", list);
request.getRequestDispatcher("car.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

i have a java script for the photo gallery that takes in an array of, ["path_to_image", "optional_link", "optional_linktarget", "optional_textdescription"].

```
imagearray: [
["path_to_image", "optional_link", "optional_linktarget", "optional_textdescription"],
["a.jpg", "www.a.com", "", ""]
],
```

I would like to retrieve the location from the object in the list passed in from the servlet and convert it into the imagearray for my photo gallery to work.

I'm quite new to javascript and i've been looking around for similar example or tutorial but i couldn't find any relevant ones. Please help me out, thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

what i get from your question is photo is an object of a class and location is a member variable of that class.

`request.setAttribute("list", list);
request.getRequestDispatcher("car.jsp").forward(request, response);`

is this `list` is a Arraylist of `photo` object or `location` member variable.

also you are setting attribute in java and you want that list to hold by javascript.
then in that case you can check JSON for holding your java object and to convert into javascript object.

you will get your string in JSON similar to
`{imagearray:[{"path_to_image":"path_to_image","optional_link":"optional_link","optional_linktarget":"optional_linktarget","optional_textdescription"}]}`

Comment: I have a photo.class and location is a String in the class. After retrieving the location from the database, i will create a new photo class and set the location to the one i've retrieve. Lastly there will be an ArrayList called 'list' to contain all these photo class. And from the javascript, i would like to retrieve all the location in each and every of the photo object and convert it into the imagearray stated above.

Comment: then try  `Gson gson = new Gson(); String photo= gson.toJson(list.list());` you will have `photo` as a string format having location variable within it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do can be simply achieved by the following sequence:

1. Get results from a database.
2. Create JSON object.
3. Set that object as request attribute.
4. Assign JSON to a JavaScript variable.

Now, let's carry on doing that list.

### Get results from database

You should have a method of type `getPhotoList()` that returns `List<Photo>`. I suppose that your `Photo` class has the fields you'd like to export to JavaScript. In the end, you'll have `List<Photo> photos` initialized.

### Create a JSON object

You can of course do that on your own, but a much better idea is to employ a specialized library that converts a java object to a JSON object. For example, you could use [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library, which is a known library for that type of conversions. In the end, you'll have a JSON object, by calling `String photosJSON = new Gson().toJson(photos);`.

### Set the JSON as a request attribute and perform a forward

Standard operation here.

```
request.setAttribute("photos", photosJSON);
request.getRequestDispatcher("car.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

### Assign JSON to a JavaScript variable

In your JSP code, within a `<script>` block, have the following line:

```
var photosJS = JSON.parse(${photos});
```

Finally, you'll have a JS variable `photosJS` with a list you got from the database.